# return (a || b) utility?

Tags: c, return

```
if (!*s1 && !*s2)
    return (1);
else if (*s1 == *s2 && *s1 != '*')
    return (match(s1 + 1, s2 + 1));
else if (*s1 == '*' && *s2 == '*')
    return (match(s1 + 1, s2));
else if (*s2 == '*' && !*s1)
    return (match(s1, s2 + 1));
else if (*s2 == '*' && *s2 && *s1)
    return (match(s1, s2 + 1) || match(s1 + 1, s2));
else
    return (0);
```

Hi guys ! I came here because I have some work to give for some school tomorrow, and as I REALLY struggled finding a way o elaborate my program, I ended up searching for some answers on the internet, which lead me to the function right on top. The thing is, I don't understand the "||" in the 10th line... why is it here for ? (I might just google it, but the thing is that I don't know what to google at all to get any answer)

Comment: Read [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/expressions#Operators) ! `||` is the boolean OR operator.

Comment: @Quentin I know it is, but as I only use it in comparisons, I don't see any why it can be used in some return function... And I did read the return docs, didn't find anything:(

Comment: There is no such thing as the "return function".  This is extremely basic C and it should be covered at the beginning of any introductory textbook.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return

Comment: As said before, I'm learning C, that's why I'm asking extremely basic questions, and using bad vocabulary when I say "return function" ... And also why I did not know I could use comparators inside things except "while" or "if"... I'm sorry if I disturb higher level programmers, but I'm here to ask help in order to progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without knowing what the code does: The statement will evaluate the first part (`match(s1, s2 + 1)`), and *if and only if* it is zero, evaluate the second part (`match(s1 + 1, s2)`). If the first part is *not* zero, it returns `true` (or 1)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually returning 1 if one of the calls to match returns 1.

It is calling match two times one with s1,s2+1 and other with s1+1,s2. If one of the call returns true, the function also returns true.